# Opened event jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, events, jquery-autocomplete

I found the jQuery UI `autocompleteopen` event, but is it possible to catch event (or override something ?) when the autocomplete list is opened ?
Actually `autocompleteopen` is fired before autocomplete list openning.

**Edit** I'm wrong ! Moderator ? Please close/delete my question :)

Comment: Can you be more precise on what you want to achieve or provide a jsFiddle ? You may add an event handler to the autocompleteopen event and use a setTimeout if the event is raised just before autocomplete is opened ($(...).autocomplete({ open: function(e) { setTimeout(..., 100) }})) ?

Comment: Use a setTimeout is not a clean way for me. Actually it's my working solution but i search a clean way to do it.

Comment: I just have a look in the jquery ui autocomplete code, and the open event is triggered AFTER calling the `_suggest(...)` function which display the menu. I also tested it with a local source and a breakpoint where event is triggered to check. Which jquery-ui version are you using ? Give us more context (code may help...)

Comment: @LPO: You're right. I missed it ! Thx's :)